# How do I manually trigger/run scripts from .gitlab-ci to test?

Tags: version-control, gitlab-ci

How do I manually trigger/run scripts from .gitlab-ci to test?

I want to test if the scripts I added in .gitlab-ci are working fine (from Gitlab)? Instead of waiting for a particular code to be pushed and enter into CI/CD pipeline of Gitlab, I want to run manually from Gitlab instead of local machines.

In other words, How to test.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: If you want to test without waiting for Gitlab you have to test it locally.

Answer (score 0):

In the Pipelines screen there is a green button called *Run pipeline*, here you can pick a branch you want to run.